# Making Firebase query act synchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a simple testing site. How it works: A user accepts a task (`assignment`), sends an answer, which is then pushed to an array called `answers`.

What I need to do, is check if the `answers` array in the `assignment` object is defined. If it is it means user has submitted at least one answer and he's good to submit.

The problem is the async. I'm not sure how to make the code wait for the query to finish.

Here's my code:

```
export default class FinishAnswerButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.handleFinishAssignment = this.handleFinishAssignment.bind(this);
    }

    async handleFinishAssignment() {
        var currentAssignment = firebase.database().ref('Works').child(this.props.assignmentId);
        console.log('props points', this.props.points);
        var outerThis = this;
        await currentAssignment.on('value', snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
        });
        var user = firebase.database().ref('Users').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
        await user.once('value', snapshot => {
            var acc = snapshot.val();
            var points = outerThis.props.points + acc.points;
            user.child('points').set(points).catch(e => console.log(e));

            // user.child('assignedWork').remove().catch(e => console.log(e));
            // currentAssignment.child('state').set('Completed').catch(e => console.log(e));
            // currentAssignment.child('finishTime').set(Time.generate()).catch(e => console.log('finishTime', e));
        });
        return <AssignmentsComponent/>
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button onClick={this.handleFinishAssignment}>Zakoncz rozwiazywanie zadania (Upewnij
                sie ze uczen ma wszystko czego potrzebuje!)</Button>
        )
    }
}
```

I tried solving it like this:

```
async handleFinishAssignment() {
    var currentAssignment = firebase.database().ref('Works').child(this.props.assignmentId);
    console.log('props points', this.props.points);
    var outerThis = this;
    currentAssignment.once('value', snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        return snapshot.val();
    }).then(assignment => { // here
        console.log(assignment);
        var user = firebase.database().ref('Users').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
        if (assignment.answers.length > 0) {
            console.log('if');
            user.once('value', snapshot => {
                var acc = snapshot.val();
                var points = outerThis.props.points + acc.points;
                user.child('points').set(points).catch(e => console.log(e));
                // user.child('assignedWork').remove().catch(e => console.log(e));
                // currentAssignment.child('state').set('Completed').catch(e => console.log(e));
                // currentAssignment.child('finishTime').set(Time.generate()).catch(e => console.log('finishTime', e));
            }).catch(e => console.log(e));
        } else
            console.log('else');
    });
    return <AssignmentsComponent/>
}
```

But it turned out, the `assignment` passed to the callback is a promise, not the actual `snapshot.val()`, which is basically what I need in the next part of the code.

Also, why does adding `await` not solve the issue? I thought the whole idea of `await` is to make the code act synchronously. Or am I using it wrong?

So to recap: I need to make this code wait. I need to use the response from the `await currentAssignment.on('value', snapshot => {` to be available in the next query, which is: `await user.once('value', snapshot => {`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have to create a function which returns a Prosime which resolves the snapshot value which you then await in the async function

Comment: Can it be done with an anonymous function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I was on the right track, but got a mental hiccup somewhere on the way. Here's the working code:

```
async handleFinishAssignment() {
    var currentAssignment = firebase.database().ref('Works').child(this.props.assignmentId);
    var outerThis = this;
    currentAssignment.once('value').then(snapshot => { // Right here
        var assignment = snapshot.val();
        console.log(assignment);
        var user = firebase.database().ref('Users').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
        if (assignment.answers !== undefined) {
            console.log('if');
            user.once('value', snapshot => {
                var acc = snapshot.val();
                var points = outerThis.props.points + acc.points;
                user.child('points').set(points).catch(e => console.log(e));
                // user.child('assignedWork').remove().catch(e => console.log(e));
                // currentAssignment.child('state').set('Completed').catch(e => console.log(e));
                // currentAssignment.child('finishTime').set(Time.generate()).catch(e => console.log('finishTime', e));
            }).catch(e => console.log(e));
        } else
            console.log('else');
    });
    return <AssignmentsComponent/>
}
```